# Drone show and swarm robotics

Tags: quadcopters

I am working for my company and we are studying swarm robotics
we would like to host a drone show for starting, and then implement swarm robotics (maybe with Agent Oriented Programming?)

We have bought 3 drones with pixhawk4: Holybro X-500 KIT (Pix32 v5) + RaspBerry4 + 4G LTE modem + Camera

How can we dive into this complex world?
any help where to start?

Answer (score 1):

This is very intersting cutting edge technology, congratulations.
I am developing an Artificial Intelligence based mainly in a Genetic Algorithm engine to be implemented on a swarm of robots/drones designed for safety porpouses. Each robot will have the same software and will act like an individual avoiding the others and the surrounding objects optimizing his path cooperatively with the rest of the swarm to reach a specific goal (ie checking for dangerous situation, delivering material or measuring temperature, gas, presence of water etc). The code is written in C++ and the main board for the robots is ESP 32 that allows a fast communication among the robots via WIFI and a decent interfacing potential.
So far a working 4x64 bits AI engine has been developed in Python as well.
If your drones support Python programming, I would suggest to start programming your drones with simple Python programs, this is a simple example:

```
from djitellopy import tello
from time import sleep
me = tello.Tello()
me.connect()
print(me.get_battery())
sleep(10)
me.takeoff()
for i in range(5):
    sleep(2)
    me.send_rc_control(0,0,0,90)
    sleep(2)
    me.send_rc_control(0,0,0,0)
sleep(2)
me.send_rc_control(0,0,40,0)
for i in range(5):
    sleep(2)
    me.send_rc_control(0,0,0,90)
    sleep(2)
    me.send_rc_control(0,0,0,0)
sleep(2)
me.land()
```

Here the drone takes off, climbs and performs a few turns and lands as an example.

I am intersted on the subject of Cooperative robot path optimization using Genetic Algoritms, Python and C++ if this helps please let me know. Thanks.